# How to scale Bucket Fill into GIMP?

Tags: gimp

I'm new with GIMP and I have lot of images for doing patterns with them.
The problem is that they are different sizes and I need secific size for specific piece of work. 
In other applications I could resize the filler tool, but here, I can't find this option...

Could someone help me, please?

Comment: Welcome on GD, La La. I wasn't able to find such an option on GIMP, there is a [script](http://registry.gimp.org/node/13707) which you can use to resize the patterns or - and perhaps is faster - you can use Imagemagick, [scale](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/) all the patterns to the desired size and use them for your work.

Comment: This has come up in our bug tracker before: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=749578 - right now, this isn't possible directly. Cloning from a scaled image source and a suitable alignment might be a possible workaround, or using the clipboard pattern.